# Server Request URL appears wrong when doing reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

My goal is so when somebody visits `main_site.com/blog`, they get served content from `other_site.com/example_blog`. Both sites run Apache 2.4 and Ubuntu (14.04 and 16.04 respectively).

I have the following code in the top of an index.php at the root of the `/var/www/html/` folder for the `other_site.com` server.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/3774582
echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
die();
```

When I visit main_site.com/blog in the browser, I get this mismatch between what the browser believes is the full URL, and what PHP believes is the full URL.

[image: URL Mismatch]

It drops off "blog" from the URL. This causes the software (WordPress in this case), to believe the user should be redirected to `main_site.com/blog` (a redirect to the URL we're already on) and it repeats this until it hits a too many redirects error.

The apache for other_site.com has not been customized other than SSL configuration. Here's the relevant apache for main_site.com

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
<Location /blog>
        ProxyPass https://blog.main_site.com
        ProxyPassReverse https://blog.main_site.com
        Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't just *believe* the `/example_blog` is missing: it actually is missing.

You should have:

```
ServerName example.com

<Location /blog>
    ProxyPass https://example.org/example_blog
    ProxyPassReverse https://example.org/example_blog
```

And you may also need to adjust Domain and Path strings in `Set-Cookie` headers:

```
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "example.org"  "example.com"
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/example_blog/"  "/blog/"
</Location>
```

Comment: I actually figured this out right before you posted this (although I'm now having other issues but that's a separate question). I don't understand the second part however. Where did example.org come from? Can you edit the question to reflect main_site.com and other_site.com respectively so I don't mix them up.

Comment: No. Instead, you should edit your question to use [RFC 6761 Example Domains](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved for this purpose, just like in my answer.